# Can someone help me with a 'NotesContext not initialized for the thread' error?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, xpages

Forgive me if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find much information about it online anywhere.

I've written some Java in Domino to pass field values to a Jasper Report and generate a PDF result.  The report consists of a subreport and a subsubreport as well.  So, essentially, I get a list of field values for the main report, one of which is an array of field values for the subreport.  In each record of the subreport array, there may be another array of field values for the subsubreport.  Pretty straightforward.

All of my Domino data retrieval is done in one bean, and I initialize the NotesContext there, so I'm confused as to why I still get this error.

Just as background... I started learning how to do this just last week and was able to pass hard coded data to a PDF successfully.  This is my first attempt at passing values from a Domino database.

Here's the DataBeanList class that gets the Domino data:

```
import java.util.*;
import lotus.domino.*;
import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;
import com.hsdomino.jasper.SubReportBeanWS;
import com.hsdomino.jasper.SubReportBeanMisc;

public class DataBeanList {
    //this class populates an object array of all the field value objects for the report
    //for subreports, there will be multiple objects in the subreport beans, one for each detail band
   public ArrayList<DataBean> getDataBeanList(String docnum) {

       //create the array to return
       ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
       //this will be a single record array consisting of a series of fields and array of ws subreport 
       //fields that contains another array of misc subsubreport fields

       try{
           NotesContext ctx = NotesContext.getCurrent();
           Session sess = ctx.getCurrentSession();
           Database db = sess.getCurrentDatabase();

           View baseview = db.getView("QuoteLetterBase_Java");
           View wsview = db.getView("QuoteLetterWS");
           View miscview = db.getView("QuoteLetterMisc");

           //get the base data
           ViewEntry ventry = baseview.getEntryByKey(docnum,true);
           String repquote = ventry.getColumnValues().get(1).toString();
           String custname = ventry.getColumnValues().get(2).toString();
           String custnum = ventry.getColumnValues().get(3).toString();
           String custadd_2 = ventry.getColumnValues().get(4).toString(); 
           String custadd_3 = ventry.getColumnValues().get(5).toString(); 
           String custadd_4 = ventry.getColumnValues().get(6).toString(); 
           String custadd_5 = ventry.getColumnValues().get(7).toString(); 
           String custadd_6 = ventry.getColumnValues().get(8).toString(); 
           String contact = ventry.getColumnValues().get(9).toString(); 
           String contactemail = ventry.getColumnValues().get(10).toString();
           String contactphone = ventry.getColumnValues().get(11).toString();
           String program = ventry.getColumnValues().get(12).toString(); 
           String inqnum = ventry.getColumnValues().get(13).toString(); 
           String fob = ventry.getColumnValues().get(14).toString(); 
           String terms = ventry.getColumnValues().get(15).toString(); 
           String estimator = ventry.getColumnValues().get(16).toString(); 
           String saleseng = ventry.getColumnValues().get(17).toString();
           String expires = ventry.getColumnValues().get(18).toString(); 
           String qnotes = ventry.getColumnValues().get(19).toString(); 
           String bottomterms = ventry.getColumnValues().get(20).toString(); 
           String tmp = ventry.getColumnValues().get(21).toString();
           Double totalquote = Double.parseDouble(tmp); 
           String docnumoption = ventry.getColumnValues().get(22).toString(); 
           String datesentoption = ventry.getColumnValues().get(23).toString();
           String id = ventry.getColumnValues().get(24).toString(); 
           String draft = ventry.getColumnValues().get(25).toString(); 
           String contactscc = ventry.getColumnValues().get(26).toString();

           //get the wsdata as an array
           ViewEntryCollection vecol = wsview.getAllEntriesByKey(docnum,true);
           ArrayList<SubReportBeanWS> wssubRepList = new ArrayList<SubReportBeanWS>();
           if(vecol.getCount()>0){
               ViewEntry wsventry = vecol.getFirstEntry();
               while(wsventry!=null){
                    String line = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(2).toString();
                    String group1 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(3).toString();
                    String group2 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(4).toString();
                    String group3 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(5).toString();
                    String group4 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(6).toString();
                    String qnotes1 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(8).toString();
                    String qnotes2 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(9).toString();
                    String qnotes3 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(10).toString();
                    String qnotes4 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(11).toString();
                    String qnotes5 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(12).toString();
                    String qnotes6 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(13).toString();
                    String qnotes7 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(14).toString();
                    String qnotes8 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(15).toString();
                    String qnotes9 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(16).toString();
                    String qnotes10 = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(17).toString();
                    String tmpws = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(18).toString();
                    Double totalquotews = Double.parseDouble(tmpws); 
                    String wsdocnum = wsventry.getColumnValues().get(19).toString();

                    //get the misc data list as an array
                    ArrayList<SubReportBeanMisc> miscsubRepList = new ArrayList<SubReportBeanMisc>();
                    ViewEntryCollection miscvecol = miscview.getAllEntriesByKey(wsdocnum,true);
                    if(miscvecol.getCount()>0){
                        ViewEntry miscventry = miscvecol.getFirstEntry();
                        while(miscventry!=null){
                            String miscgroup1 = miscventry.getColumnValues().get(3).toString();
                            String tmpmisc = miscventry.getColumnValues().get(9).toString();
                            Double totalquotemisc = Double.parseDouble(tmpmisc); 

                            //create a misc bean to store in the misc array
                            SubReportBeanMisc miscsubbean = new SubReportBeanMisc();
                            miscsubbean.setGroup1(miscgroup1);
                            miscsubbean.setTotalquote(totalquotemisc);
                            miscsubRepList.add(miscsubbean);

                            ViewEntry tmpmiscve = miscvecol.getNextEntry(miscventry);
                            miscventry.recycle();
                            miscventry = tmpmiscve;
                        }
                    }
                    miscvecol.recycle();

                    //create a ws bean to store in the base array
                    SubReportBeanWS wssubbean = new SubReportBeanWS();
                    wssubbean.setLine(line);
                    wssubbean.setGroup1(group1);
                    wssubbean.setGroup2(group2);
                    wssubbean.setGroup3(group3);
                    wssubbean.setGroup4(group4);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes1(qnotes1);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes2(qnotes2);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes3(qnotes3);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes4(qnotes4);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes5(qnotes5);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes6(qnotes6);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes7(qnotes7);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes8(qnotes8);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes9(qnotes9);
                    wssubbean.setQnotes10(qnotes10);
                    wssubbean.setTotalquote(totalquotews);
                    wssubbean.setWsdocnum(wsdocnum);
                    wssubbean.setSubReportBeanMiscList(miscsubRepList);

                    wssubRepList.add(wssubbean);

                   ViewEntry tmpve = vecol.getNextEntry(wsventry);
                   wsventry.recycle();
                   wsventry = tmpve;
               }

               vecol.recycle();
           }

           //create the base quote bean array
           dataBeanList.add(produce(docnum,repquote,custname,custnum,custadd_2,custadd_3,custadd_4,custadd_5,custadd_6,contact,contactemail,contactphone,
                   program,inqnum,fob,terms,estimator,saleseng,expires,qnotes,bottomterms,totalquote,docnumoption,datesentoption,id,draft,contactscc,wssubRepList));

           ventry.recycle();
           baseview.recycle();
           wsview.recycle();
           miscview.recycle();
       }
       catch(NotesException e){
           System.out.println("Error in DataBeanList: " + e);
       }

       return dataBeanList;
   }

   /**
    * This method returns a DataBean object,
    * with all the fields for the main report in it (and an array for the WS subreport
    * which contains an array for th misc subreport)
    */
   private DataBean produce(String qnum, String repquote, String custname, String custnum, String custadd_2, 
           String custadd_3, String custadd_4, String custadd_5, String custadd_6, String contact, String contactemail,
           String contactphone, String program, String inqnum, String fob, String terms, String estimator, String saleseng,
           String expires, String qnotes, String bottomterms, Double totalquote, String docnumoption, String datesentoption,
           String id, String draft, String contactscc, List<SubReportBeanWS> subBean) {
      DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
      dataBean.setDocnum(qnum);
      dataBean.setRepquote(repquote);
      dataBean.setCustname(custname);
      dataBean.setCustnum(custnum);
      dataBean.setCustadd_2(custadd_2);
      dataBean.setCustadd_3(custadd_3);
      dataBean.setCustadd_4(custadd_4);
      dataBean.setCustadd_5(custadd_5);
      dataBean.setCustadd_6(custadd_6);
      dataBean.setContact(contact);
      dataBean.setContactemail(contactemail);
      dataBean.setContactphone(contactphone);
      dataBean.setProgram(program);
      dataBean.setInqnum(inqnum);
      dataBean.setFob(fob);
      dataBean.setTerms(terms);
      dataBean.setEstimator(estimator);
      dataBean.setSaleseng(saleseng);
      dataBean.setExpires(expires);
      dataBean.setQnotes(qnotes);
      dataBean.setBottomterms(bottomterms);
      dataBean.setTotalquote(totalquote);
      dataBean.setDocnumoption(docnumoption);
      dataBean.setDatesentoption(datesentoption);
      dataBean.setId(id);
      dataBean.setDraft(draft);
      dataBean.setContactscc(contactscc);
      dataBean.setSubReportBeanWSList(subBean);

      return dataBean;
   }
}
```

And, here's the error stack:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:227)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
    at com.ibm.xsp.actions.ExecuteScriptAction.invoke(ExecuteScriptAction.java:78)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.broadcast(UIDataIterator.java:694)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=4, col=5: Error calling method 'reportToFile(string)' on java class 'com.hsdomino.jasper.CreatePDF'
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:335)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error in CreatePDF: 
    at com.hsdomino.jasper.CreatePDF.reportToFile(CreatePDF.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:322)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new java.lang.Integer(1)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:874)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:536)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:411)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:386)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2024)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:929)
    at com.hsdomino.jasper.CreatePDF.reportToFile(CreatePDF.java:53)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new java.lang.Integer(1)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:352)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluateEstimated(JRCalculator.java:607)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.estimateVariables(JRCalculator.java:208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1250)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1056)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:736)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:416)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:842)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:829)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
    at HSD_QuoteWS_Java_1492633388584_6145.evaluateEstimated(HSD_QuoteWS_Java_1492633388584_6145:599)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:338)
    ... 14 more
```

The main class runs through everything fine to get the data, but then produces the error at this line:

```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,beanColDataSource);
```

I know this from tracking it on the Domino console:

```
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:51 PM  HTTP JVM: setting reportname
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:51 PM  HTTP JVM: setting parameters
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:51 PM  HTTP JVM: setting beancol datasrc
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:51 PM  HTTP JVM: setting base data
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: setting wsdata for line 1.
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: - - - checking misc data
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: getting misc data for line 1.
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: setting subreportbeanws
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: setting databeanlist
[17E0:000D-1F9C] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: calling jasperfillmgr
[17E0:0163-2300] 04/20/2017 02:49:52 PM  HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/XWork/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

The main class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class CreatePDF implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CreatePDF(){
        //for managed bean
    }

       public void reportToFile(String docnum) {

           try {
System.out.println("setting reportname");
           String jasperReport = "C://Users/RPo/Documents/BobC/Jasper Reports/Studio Reports/MyReports/HSD_Quote_Java.jasper";
           String subReportWS = "C://Users/RPo/Documents/BobC/Jasper Reports/Studio Reports/MyReports/HSD_QuoteWS_Java.jasper";
           String subReportMisc = "C://Users/RPo/Documents/BobC/Jasper Reports/Studio Reports/MyReports/HSD_QuoteMisc_Java.jasper";
           String destReport = "C:/JReports/HSD/"+docnum+".pdf";

System.out.println("setting parameters");
       // Parameters for report
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("SubReportWS", subReportWS); 
        parameters.put("SubReportMisc", subReportMisc); 

       // DataSource
System.out.println("setting beancol datasrc");              
          DataBeanList DataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
          ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(docnum);
          JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

System.out.println("calling jasperfillmgr");
       JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,beanColDataSource);

System.out.println("calling exporttopdf");
       // Export to PDF.
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,destReport);

       System.out.println("Done!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in CreatePDF: " + e);
                throw new RuntimeException("error in CreatePDF: ", e);
            }
   }
}
```

I call the code from ssjs like this:

```
var docnum = rdata.getColumnValue("_DocNum");
var pdf = new com.hsdomino.jasper.CreatePDF;
pdf.reportToFile(docnum)
```

This jrxml data wont fit in this post (grrrr).

Can someone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

UPDATE 25APR17, I removed the subreport and it worked perfectly!  So, narrowing my focus to that.

Comment: Which Domino version are you running this on?  Is this a managed bean or an unmanaged bean?

Comment: I'm using Domino 9.0.1 and the main class is a managed bean, here it is:

Comment: Your template (*jrxml*) is wrong, because you got `JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new java.lang.Integer(1)` error

Comment: How do you invoke that? Stacktrace shows you have some SSJS call invoking it.

Comment: Yes, I saw that integer reference as well, but I'm not using any integers anywhere, so I didn't understand it.  (I double checked my jasper reports and my variable declarations).  Yes, Frantisek, I'm calling my code from ssjs like this (see the post)  I just now tried adding the serializable lines, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Show your jrxml the stacktrace points to that.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Petter.  I tried to put my jrxml in the post, but the character limit won't let me.  Is there another way to post it? - or, can you give me a suggestion for what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get session from XPages (JSF) engine like this:

```
Session session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same result using that.